# Can all of fork(), exec() and system() be wrong?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, c, openbsd, posix

I understand why it could be less than best practice if I write C code that executes shell commands by calling `system()` and that it's better to use `exec` and `fork` but then a very experienced C programmer told me that it's wrong to make a shell by forking and execing but he never answered why. Can you tell me? I could have misunderstood by my code for my [custom new shell](http://github.com/montao/openshell) uses `fork` and `exec` to execute a pipeline that I can enter at a prompt.

Did he mean that the best shell also implements the programs from `/bin` ? I quote the experienced C programmer but I don't understand why he told me this.

> having C code which forks & pipes several programs inside your shell is IMHO quite wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two main reasons to run a program directly without calling the shell are:

- Performance: Most programs that you would call from your C program are likely much smaller than the shell, which makes them start much more quickly.
- Environment control: Dealing with an additional layer of environment variables to deal with can be more complex to configure and troubleshoot.